# Marklogic - How to get list of user with roles

Tags: xquery, marklogic

How to construct xquery to retrieve a list of user name and roles name. thanks in advance for any sample xquery code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would just need to query the documents in the Security database. As an admin, you can do this by putting the query inside an `xdmp:invoke-function()` like so:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace sec="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/security" at 
    "/MarkLogic/security.xqy";

xdmp:invoke-function(function() {
    for $user in //sec:user
    let $user-name := $user/sec:user-name/text()
    let $roles := sec:user-get-roles($user-name)
    return 
    <user>
      <user-name>{$user-name}</user-name>
      <roles>
        {for $role in $roles return <role>{$role}</role>}
      </roles>
    </user>
    }, 
    <options xmlns="xdmp:eval">
      <database>{xdmp:security-database()}</database>
    </options>)
```

Comment: Hi, this is a very helpful post for me. But also can you suggest me how can I get the output of this query in excel format.?